# A headless Mac Mini server gets stuck (non-SSH-able) after rebooting (macOS Mojave)

Tags: macos, mojave, ssh

When I reboot a headless Mac Mini server running macOS Mojave with sudo reboot, it becomes non-ssh-able. The same happens if a "fake monitor" HDMI display emulator is plugged in. This happens consistently with multiple Mac Mini machines. Interestingly, a "hard reboot" (holding the power button until the machine switches off, and then turning it on again) allows the host to come back online, even without plugging in a monitor.

Also, this issue does not happen if a real monitor is plugged in -- in this case the machine reboots fine and comes back online.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious thing to check is if you have FileVault enabled and attach a display simulator dongle. In the FileVault case, the machine does not restart to the OS but to a firmware / limited log in screen, but having a display connected won’t enable/disable FileVault.

You will want to have a remote KVM or someone that can log in for unexpected power failures. See this thread for a lot more options like power, display and management options for headless Macs.

- [Remote into Mac Mini after a reboot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/233853/remote-into-mac-mini-after-a-reboot)
- [Rebooting a headless Mac Mini](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69335/rebooting-a-headless-mac-mini)

Removing FileVault would allow the OS to boot fully in exchange for the data not being encrypted at rest.

Comment: I have a Mac mini M1 without attached display, keyboard, and mouse, but only LAN and power plug. I also met the ssh and Chrome Remote Desktop problem after rebooting macOS.

Fortunately, I work around the problem by disabling FileVault!

Comment: Good point @Meng-YuanHuang I should edit that in as something explicitly to try in the post above.